# How to turn on bitlocker on 4 TB USB HDD?

Tags: windows-7, usb, external-hard-drive, bitlocker

When trying to turn on Bitlocker on an external 4 TB USB HDD using Windows 7, there's error *A device attached to the system is not functioning.* in a rather unhelpful dialog, as shown below:

[image]

Now according to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/591749/bitlocker-wont-initialize-on-a-4tb-drive-with-4k-sectors), there are a few solutions, but the answers aren't very detailed. First of all, the solution in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/630363/246098) (uninstall [KB2799926](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2799926)) is unlikely to work I suppose, because this is external drive and uninstalling that would disable using Bitlocker on it completely. And then answers lack an exact way to format the drive to the maximum capacity, if that's the only way on external drive. So I'm looking for a succinct answer to these:

- Does uninstalling [KB2799926](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2799926) and then reinstalling it later work or not, with external drives?
- What's the exact command/method to format the drive to maximum working capacity?
- Other known-to-work ways to enable Bitlocker on the drive, like acquiring a Win8 PC to do it?

Comment: Is the drive NTFS formatted? If you try to [turn on BitLocker using the command-line interface](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff829873.aspx) you should get the exact error code.

Comment: Hahaha, marked as a duplicate when that other question is referring to an internal drive, and the solution offered is to disable a hotfix which will disable BitLocker on external drives, exactly what this question is about.  Do you people read things before marking as duplicate?

Comment: @and31415 "manage-bde -G: -pw" --> "ERROR: Invalid Syntax. -G: was not understood."     Nice work as always Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

I run in a similar issue using a partition on my disk. I found out that my perfect 30g partition was too close to the next one.
I had to shrink it by 18 MB (17 not working and about 18 working) to make BitLocker work.
So of course it was not linked to any "driver" issue, just partition size and free space after the partition issue.

Now, 18MB might be a ratio and it is indicated [BitLocker Drive Encryption in Windows 7: Frequently Asked Questions](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ee449438(v=ws.10).aspx) that the minimum size must be 64 MB (55 MB according to [Why does BitLocker need a minimum volume size of 64 MB?](https://superuser.com/questions/762787/why-does-bitlocker-need-a-minimum-volume-size-of-64-mb))

Extract from technet.microsoft.com

*BitLocker hardware and software requirements for data drives
Requirement Description*

*The drive must be least 64 MB in size.*

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise, be sure you tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: @David Read that other question, they are *not* the same.

Comment: @Francois, how did you determine this is what you had to do?  I have a Seagate 8TB external drive and am getting the same error, Google is turning up absolutely nothing on how to resolve this.

Comment: @tbone - I wasn't referring to the answer linked, but to another another by Francois that appears to have been deleted.

Comment: @tbone I had the exact same Error message window on a smaller partition and resolved it by leaving a bigger gap between partitions, Now I did not try it on a 4 TB disk. The NTFS limit with default is 16 TB and Bitlocker follows filesystem limitation. In the absence of other explanation, I suggested it to be the raison (ie need to leave a gap after the partition to be encrypted)
Regards

Comment: @Francois So are you saying I need to partition this external disk into one big partition and one small partition, then BitLocker should work?  It's bizarre that wouldn't be documented anywhere.

Comment: Hi @tbone. Do not create a small partition after. You should leave a gap (unpartitioned) .  IE, if your disk is 4TiB, do not create one big partition of exactly 4 TiB, create it 3.98 TiB (=4075 GiB) and leave some unused space after (no partition)
If it works, try to extend it to 7.96 TiB. It looks like that bitlocker is using/needing some extra buffer (unused/unpartition) after the partition.
Basically you cannot use the whole space to your partition.
I would recommend to start small (eg 0.98 TiB, try to bitlocked it; then extend the size by doubling it). I needed (30GiB - 18MiB)=30702 MiB

Comment: @Francois Well, I created a smaller partition resulting in 6.5TB of disk space (compared to 7.2 or so before?), but exact same error.  Perhaps this drive simply cannot be BitLocked?  (I contacted Seagate tech support and they said ask Microsoft)

Comment: Hi @tbone, I have a 5 TO Seagate disk. I just created a **logical** 2.2 TiB partition7 and i did bitlocked it. I left 1800 MB unpartitioned at the end.
_NB:I had to use EaseUS partiton to increase my extended partition as diskmgr limited_


DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset

  Partition 1    Primary            556 MB     8 MB

  Partition 0    Extended          4656 GB   564 MB
  Partition 2    Logical            466 GB   565 MB
..
  Partition 6    Logical            465 GB  1689 GB

  Partition 7    Logical           2502 GB  2154 GB